# the method AvailableMetadataObjectTypes in the class AVCaptureMetadataOutput looks like it is declared wrongly

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

in Xamarin for iOS the class **AVCaptureMetadataOutput** has a method **AvailableMetadataObjectTypes** which according to the Micro*soft* docs and assembly is declared as this

```
public AVMetadataObjectType AvailableMetadataObjectTypes {
    [MethodImpl (MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    get
```

but the Apple documentation and sample objective C code suggest it should return an NSArray

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray<AVMetadataObjectType> *availableMetadataObjectTypes;
```

Question which is correct and how would I use this method in C# (xamarin)

As a side question what is the C# equivalent of **NSSet**.

thanks all

Christian Stœr Arild Andersen

Answer (score 0):

OK I am beginning to suspect that **AvailableMetadataObjectTypes** is an **ENUM** not an **NSArray** in xamarin.io .

I will leave the question here just in case someone else comes across this